# How to get string starting and ending with something, containing a substring?

Tags: regex

I'm new to regex and I am trying to grab urls from a big html-text file. The links are "trapped" in the following types of strings:

`,&quot;link_value&quot;:&quot;https://www.linkedin.com/company/randomcompanyA&quot;},&quot;event&quot;:&quot;link_click&`

I want to write a regex line that will get me any string starting and ending with `&quot;`, *containing* `linkedin` or `instagram` etc. In other words, I want to grab strings/links by defining a substring in that link, so I do not want a general line returning all links in a file. So far I've been able to write the following:

```
(?<=&quot;).+?(?=&quot;)
```

But I'm not able to work in the 'contains linkedin' part in there. The above command would therefore also return `link_value`, for example.

Any help is appreciated!

Comment: Using regex101.com to test it, it doesn't seem to catch the link. Moreover, I'd like something where I can decide which link it returns, e.g. a youtube link, facebook etc.

Comment: @anubhava Ah, I was using a new version. Still though, I need something to grab links by defining substrings. This would grab any link.

Comment: ok, check my updated answer below.

Comment: What language/tool are you using? From the [regex tag info](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/regex/info): "Since regular expressions are not fully standardized, all questions with this tag should also include a tag specifying the applicable programming language or tool."

Comment: @Toto I'm not sure actually. My plan is to just `import re` in python and get going. I was using regex101.com to test around with my lines.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you're already using look arounds, you can make your regex more specific by starting your match with `http://` or `https://` like this:

```
(?<=&quot;)https?:\/\/[^\/]*?\b(?:linkedin|instagram)\.\S+?(?=&quot;)
```

[RegEx Demo](https://regex101.com/r/S5NH9m/2/)

**RegEx Details:**

- `https?:\/\/` will match `http://` or `https://`
- `[^\/]*?` matches 0 or more of any character that is not `/` (lazy)
- `\b(?:linkedin|instagram)\.` will match any of the given strings in the link followed by a dot.
- `\S+?` matches 1 or more of any character that is not a whitespace (lazy)

Comment: Very nice, this is what I need. Could you explain in a bit more detail what the parts `[^\/]*?`and `\S+?` do?

Comment: I have added more explanation in answer.

Comment: Hi, sorry to bother you again. I am trying to use this command in the latest Python, but it is not catching the string. Trying it on regex101.com shows it should work in Python, but it isn't for me. It looks like the \b part is colored differently in Python. Do you happen to have any idea?

Comment: It works perfectly fine in python3. Just use `re.findall(r'(?<=&quot;)https?://[^/]*?\b(?:linkedin|instagram)\.\S+?(?=&quot;)', string)`

Comment: Ah, I was missing the r in front of my string. Thanks alot.

Answer (score 0):

this regex will grab URLs regardless the "quot" tags

```
https?:\/\/(www\.)?[-a-zA-Z0-9@:%._\+~#=]{1,256}\.[a-zA-Z0-9()]{1,6}\b([-a-zA-Z0-9()@:%_\+.~#?&//=]*)
```

Tell me if it works

Comment: Thanks for the answer! However, my comment above also holds for your answer sadly.